# How to find adjacent td of a speicifc column of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to control a specific column of a table using jQuery.

I would like to select the next or the previous td contained in the column number 5 starting, for istance, from the second one and change the related text or css properties of the adjecent ones.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').eq(0).addClass('change');
```

The column can contains 3 or more than 100 td. I tried to use the method next() and previous

```
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').eq(0).next();
```

but I could not select the adjacent ones.

This is the example:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/garaux/59faenqq/1/)

Comment: adjacent - is taht the cells above and below, or the ones to the left or the right?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: do you want to select the element of next row are same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to select elements form next row

```
    $('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').eq(0).closest('tr')
                                            .next()
                                            .find('td:nth-child(5)').css({'background-color':'green','color':'#fff'});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/59faenqq/9/)

> jsut use prev to select previous td of same row

```
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').prev()
                                         .eq(0)
                                         .css({'background-color':'green','color':'#fff'});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/59faenqq/6/)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to select all td contained in the column number 5

In this case you just need to remove `eq(0)` from your current code, as that is restricting the selection to the first `td` found:

```
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').addClass('change');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59faenqq/5/)

---

> I would like to select the next or the previous td

In this case use `prev()` and `next()` to find it:

```
var $td = $('table.pl_res_game tr td:eq(1)');
$td.next().add($td.prev()).addClass('direct-sibling');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59faenqq/8/)

Comment: Hi Rory, I did not express properly what I am trying to achieve. Sorry. My question is: I would like to select the next or the previous td contained in the column number 5 starting, for istance, from the second one. Take into consideration that the column could contain more than 100 td

Answer (score 0):

try modifing the index of the eq() like in the sample below:

```
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').eq(1).css({'background-color':'green','color':'#fff'});
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').eq(2).css({'background-color':'green','color':'#fff'});
```

and so on

You can then use a for loop for the range you want to select:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
$('table.pl_res_game tr td:nth-child(5)').eq(i).css({'background-color':'green','color':'#fff'});
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9h35atrb/)

Comment: Hi Simone, yes, I know: I could use the eq() for each td, but, as I explained above, the column could contain more than 100 td and my goal is to manage it using a dynamic method to get the next one and the previous one.